# ArUco Movement Tracking

Tags: python, opencv, aruco, realsense

I'm trying to use ArUco to track the movement of an ArUco marker using Python. Does anyone have Python code for this or know where to get it?

I already have code to track changes in the orientation of an ArUco marker, but for my project specifically, I need to track the movement of an ArUco marker as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: welcome. research is expected of you. [ask]. did you find the official opencv documentation at least?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , I have found a solution. Thank you though!